# Get URL of current page in C# with AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, routes, singlepage

I am working on tracking system for my SignalR Hub purpose. For this I have class where I want to store URL which will represent current page where user is, then his last request since I use paged list for my data tables and I need to know exactly on which page user is and of course user id.

This is my class where I want to store information

```
public class UserTracking
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string LastRequest { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Since I have a single page application I have problem with tracking user position on website because of angular routing, but for displaying views I have dashboard controller with ActionResults methods to allow me to display `.cshtml` pages with angular routing, something like this below

```
public ActionResult ProjectTask()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Project()
{
    return View();
}
```

My question is if I am able somehow to get URL of user position on my website. For example if user is on `http://localhost:2969/Dashboard#/tasks/` I want to get this `/Dashboard#/tasks`. Maybe I can get some information from my ActionResults, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know if this will work for you with the information you've provided, but the following could work.

If you know the specific routes that a user *must* navigate to to reach you MVC Controller then you could pass in that information as a model when you return the view. Say I have an MVC route that is meant to return a Razor page that displays all the items from my list named "Freddy's Birthday". The URL in this case would look something like:

```
localhost/list/Freddy's%20Birthday
```

matching a route:

```
[Route("~/list/{id}")]
```

To inform Angular of what you're dealing with, simply pass in the information as a model:

```
public ActionResult List(string id)
{
    return View(model: id);
}
```

You can access that model in your cshtml with @Model. If the id passed in was "Freddy's Birthday" like before:

```
<div todo-list-item-directive>@Model</div>
```

Would return from ASP as:

```
<div todo-list-item-directive>Freddy's Birthday</div>
```

This way works, and you could build some view models to reference in your Razor pages if you need to pass in more complicated information. However, if at all possible, it'd likely be worth your while to set up ui-router and use Angular for your view routing and ASP.NET for your API.